# Bulk trigger new flow on all existing records (5000)

Tags: workflow, field-update, bulk

I just created a new flow that would populate a field based on the value in another long text field when a record is created or updated. The flow is fairly heavy, but runs quite well when entering new records. I now want to apply this too all existing records.

As I hate the import wizard, I usually use the google sheets Salesforce tool when doing mass import/update. When trying to update everything, I get the error:

> We can't save this record because the â€œ*process name*â€ process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. **Limit Exceeded**
> You or your organization has exceeded the maximum limit for this feature. Error ID: 22030709-348913 (824709315)organization has exceeded the maximum limit for this feature. Error ID: 22030709-348913 (824709315)

I tried reducing the amount of records that I update, and 100 seemed to be the max where everything still works.

I tried using the data loader, but even at 100 records the tool wouldn't work.

Is there a way to easily trigger the flow on all existing records?

Comment: You're getting limit exception, basically your transaction took more than 10seconds to complete. There must be something that is going in recursion.

Comment: so, why not use Data Loader and set the batch size to 25 (or 50)?  Then let it rip and go do something else.